# Select data from multiple tables with different name and columns

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql

I have this problem that I can't resolve. In CMS Joomla I need to select data from table `#__adsmanager_ads` column `ad_healine` **and** from table `#__modules` column `title`.
Then check `if ad_headline == title` load module (that equal to ad_healine)

I use this code for single table select:

```
<?php
 Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
 // Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('ad_headline')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__adsmanager_ads'));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $results = $db->loadObjectList();
    $objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($results),true); // Convert stdClass object to array
    print_r($objectoarr);     
  ?>
```

=========================================================================
Next i write code below and problem is almost solver

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query 
    ->select (array('a.ad_headline', 'b.title')) //Select columns from database
    ->from ($db->quoteName('#__adsmanager_ads','a'))
    ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__modules', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.ad_headline') . '=' . $db->quoteName('b.title').')');
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
$objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($result),true); // Convert stdClass object to array

foreach ($objectoarr as $adhealine){
        if ($adhealine[ad_headline] === $adhealine[title])
        {
            $document = &JFactory::getDocument();
            $renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
            $position   = 'inside-ad';
            $options   = array('style' => 'raw');
            echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null); 
        }
}
?>
```

But problem is that all modules set to position `inside-ad` loading there. But I need load only module which's name  equivalent to ads name.

How can i solve this problem? Thank in advance

Comment: If you'd rather work with the result set as an array of arrays rather than an array of objects, then you shouldn't call `loadObjectList()` you should call `loadAssocList()`.  this way you can avoid `$objectoarr = json_decode(json_encode($result),true);` which is obviously the long way around.  I would be using an INNER JOIN to eliminate the possibility of joining to NULL rows.  Since the INNER JOIN will ensure that you are only getting identical `ad_headline` and `title` values in each row, you can omit the php conditional: `if ($adhealine[ad_headline] === $adhealine[title])`.

Comment: Did you manage to self-solve this issue or is this still a mystery to you?  Are all of the modules being targeted in your query ALSO `position = 'inside-ad'`?  Is it necessary to write into the query as a `WHERE` condition?  Please progress all of  your questions toward a system-recognized resolution.  This is important to this this community for so many reasons.  Please add your complete and educational answer or update your question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `join` in your query to pull back just the records where the module title is the same as the ad headline, so, start by reading this [Joomla Docs page](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_Multiple_Tables) and the [MySQL page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html). Then you will need to create a query something like:

```
$query->from('#__adsmanager_ads AS ads');
$query->select('ads.ad_headline')
      ->join(
             'LEFT',
             $db->quoteName('#__modules') . ' ON m.title = ads.ad_headline'
             )
```

**N.B.** _Please note I've just typed this into the browser, so it's probably got mistakes in it.